# Golang's syscall/js js.NewCallback is undefined

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

I am new to both go and wasm and it looks like these projects are pretty fast moving. [I was reading an introduction to using wasm in go](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/compiling-go-to-webassembly/) and it seems although it was written in January, its already out of date.

I am attempting to call a single go function when a JavaScript function is invoked. The example says to do something like this:

```
 js.Global().Set("jsFunctionName", js.NewCallback(goCallback))
```

Although when I am trying to compile this, I am getting this error:

```
./webassembly.go:54:35: undefined: js.NewCallback
```

[I checked the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/) and see no reference to `NewCallback`. What is the current "correct" way that this should be done?

Comment: Did you import `syscall/js` and set the proper environment variables (`GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm`)?

Comment: It looks like the article you're referring to may be outdated. You may want to checkout [the wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly). If I had to guess, you might want `js.FuncOf` instead of `js.NewCallback`.

Comment: @Gavin Thank you for the recommendation! It looks like js.FuncOf is what im looking for. Once I test it out and make sure it does what im looking for, ill reply to the question with the solution that worked for me. Thank you again!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
js.Global().Set("jsFunctionName", js.NewCallback(goCallback))
```

should be as:

```
js.Global().Set("jsFunctionName", js.FuncOf(goCallback))
```

Note the signature of goCallback has changed and now since Go 1.12, there is a support  for return values.
For example, here is how to expose a simple add function:

```
// function definition
func add(this js.Value, i []js.Value) interface{} {
  return js.ValueOf(i[0].Int()+i[1].Int())
}

// exposing to JS
js.Global().Set("add", js.FuncOf(add))
```